# I have to write a procedure in postgresql, which will find the maximum value of column having alphanumeric value(text) like 'RAM-1', 'RAM-2'

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a column name as Item_code which have the values like 'RAM-1','RAM-2', 'RAM-2'....'RAM-12'. I have to write procedure in postgreSQL which find maximum value from this column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_last_itemcode(
item text)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
declare 
result text;      
BEGIN
   Select MAX(it.item_code) into result from public.items as it where it.item_name = item;

   return result;
END;
$BODY$;
```

But it gives the value maximum value 'RAM-9, instead of 'RAM-15'.

Comment: It does give you the correct answer: 9 comes after 1. When sorting text, it doesn’t matter that there’s also a 5 after the 1 to make it number (!) 15. Store numbers as a number, not text.

Comment: That's why I need a query that helps out to filter the max value from text....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should satisfy the stated requirements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_last_itemcode(item items.item_name%type)
  RETURNS items.item_code%type
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  STRICT
  AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  last_itemcode items.item_code%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT items.item_code
    INTO last_itemcode
    FROM items
   WHERE items.item_name = get_last_itemcode.item
   ORDER BY regexp_replace(items.item_code, '^.*-(\d+)$', '\1')::integer DESC
   LIMIT 1;

  RETURN last_itemcode;
END
$BODY$;
```

`STRICT` has been specified since the function will always return NULL if *item* is NULL. All of the column and variable references in the query are qualified to protect against name collisions. Type declarations reference the relevant table columns to help protect against incompatible schema changes.

Answer (score 0):

To get the max, you will need to descending order records by the extracted number from `item_code`, then take the first one using `LIMIT 1`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_last_itemcode(item text)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
declare 
result text;      
BEGIN
   Select item_code into result
   from public.items 
   where item_name = item
   order by REGEXP_REPLACE(item_code, '.*-(^0-9)*', '\1')::int desc
   limit 1;

   return result;
END;
$BODY$;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/i0h8-EFy)

Comment: There is a subtle defect in this answer: if _item_name_ includes any digits, then "invalid syntax for type integer" will be raised.

Comment: No it never happens. Name is always in text and have no number. It works perfectly.